# Set Navbar hidden = false don't work

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

i have 2 ViewController

VC A and VC B

VC A => NavigationBar Hidden = true

VC B => NavigationBar Hidden = false

I make a segue from A => B, but the navgiationbar in VC B is not visible.

i have include the following swift code in vc b:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false and/or placing it in viewDidLoad

Comment: thank you, but same result :/

Answer (score 4):

if you are using

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true;
```

use this to show Bar

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false;
```

not to use

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false;
```

please check that

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar and the tool bar should disappear in the storyboard when you change the segue -- that's normal.

Try checking [image]

**Following should work with iOS 8 for a particular view**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

**To show on all viewControllers place it in viewDidLoad**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following work around

in your VC A viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

    }
```

Comment: are you sure you have not check hide navigation bar in storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

In your VC A use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

And in VC B use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: new information, my vc b is embeded in a navigation controller. the segue form vc a => b is a modal segue

Answer (score 0):

VC A and VC B embedded in Navigation controller here and I have this working.

In VC A i have the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

and in B I have

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

works perfectly